# Oracle query to count rows based on value from next record

Tags: oracle11g

Input values to the query : 1-20
Values in the database : 4,5, 15,16

I would like a query that gives me results as following

```
Value - Count
===== - =====
1     - 3    
6     - 9
17    - 3
```

So basically, first generate continuous numbers from 1 to 20, count available numbers. 
I wrote a query but I can not get it to fully work:

```
with avail_ip as (
      SELECT (0) + LEVEL AS val
      FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL < 20),
  grouped_tab as (
  select val,lead(val,1,0) over (order by val) next_val 
  from avail_ip u
  where not exists (
    select 'x' from (select 4 val from dual) b
    where b.val=u.val)  )
  select 
    val,next_val-val difference,
    count(*) over (partition by next_val-val) avail_count
  from grouped_tab
  order by 1
```

It gives me count but i am not sure how to compress the rows to just three rows.

I was not able to add complete query, I kept getting 'error occurred while submission'. For some reason it does not like union clause. So I am attaching query as a image :(

[image: Query image]

More details of exact requirement:

I am writing a ip management module and i need to find out available (free) ip addresses within a ip block. Block could be /16 or /24 or even /12. To make it even challenging, i also support IPv6 so will have lot more numbers to manage. All issued ip addresses are stored in decimal format. So my thought is to first generate all ip decimals within the block range from network address to broadcast address. For eg. in a /24, there would 255 addresses and in case of /16 would 64K.

Now, secondly find all used addresses within a block, and find out available number of address with a starting ip. So in the above example, starting 1 ip- 3 addresses are available, starting with 6, 9 are available  .

My last concern would be the query should be able to run fast enough to run through millions of numbers.

And sorry again, if my original question was not clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar sort of idea to what you tried:

```
with all_values as (
  select :start_val + level - 1 as val
  from dual
  connect by level <= (:end_val - :start_val) + 1
),
missing_values as (
  select val
  from all_values
  where not exists (select null from t42 where id = val)
),
chains as (
  select val,
    val - (row_number() over (order by val) + :start_val - 1) as chain
  from missing_values
)
select min(val), count(*) - 1 as gap_count
from chains
group by chain
order by min(val);
```

With `start_val` as 1 and `end_val` as 20, and your data in table `t42`, that gets:

```
  MIN(VAL)  GAP_COUNT
---------- ----------
         1          3 
         6          9 
        17          4
```

I've made `end_val` inclusive though; not sure if if you want it to be inclusive or exclusive. And I've perhaps made it more flexible that you need - your version also assumes you're always starting from 1.

The `all_values` CTE is basically the same as your, generating all the numbers between the start and end values - 1 to 20 (inclusive!) in this case.

The `missing_values` CTE removes the values that are in the table, so you're left with `1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,18,19,20`.

The `chains` CTE does the magic part. This gets the difference between each value and where you would expect it to be in a contiguous list. The difference - what I've called 'chain' - is the same for all contiguous missing values; 1,2,3 all get 0, 6 to 14 all get 2, and 17 to 20 all get 4. That chain value can then be used to group by, and you can use the aggregate count and min to get the answer you need.

[SQL Fiddle of a simplified version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cb56a/2) that is specifically for 1-20, showing the data from each intermediate step. This would work for any upper limit, just by changing the 20, but assumes you'll always start from 1.

Comment: That is perfect!. Exactly what i needed. And excellent explanation. And sorry for lack of details in my original question as i was having difficult time adding my query for some reason. Let me ask you this. Is this query good enough to handle over a million numbers from first query? You know what I am going to add more details to my original question.